# SQL Server : join using index containing field in select, instead of join on PK

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I'm looking for some information on how Microsoft SQL Server (specifically 2016 in my case) decides on which index to use for joins. Most of the time it seems to work well, but other times I have to scratch my head...

Here is a simple query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderMaster.StartDate, Employee.EmpName   
FROM 
    OrderMaster
INNER JOIN 
    Employee ON OrderMaster.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
```

`EmpId` is the PK (`int`) on the `Employee` table.

There are 2 indexes on `Employee`: `PK_Employee`, which is a clustered PK index on `EmpId`, and `IX_Employee_EmpName` which is a nonclustered index, and only uses column `EmpName`.

This query returns 500 order records, but has performed an Index Scan using `IX_Employee_EmpName` on the `Employee` table, which reads 30,000 records.

Why would it have picked this index, instead of doing an index seek on `PK_Employee`?

What is the preferred method to solve this problem? Would I specify that the join use the `PK_Employee` index, or should I create a new index on `EmpId`, but includes the additional columns I may pull from selecting (empname, address, etc)?

Comment: Can you share your Execution plan too? It will be interesting to see what else is happening in the execution plan also since you haven't mentioned any where clause (not filtering any rows at all) any index it touches it will have to scan it. If you had any where clause limiting the number of rows being returned then maybe SQL Server would have done some sort of Seek.

Comment: Side note, if I change Employee.EmpName to Employee.Address (which is not a part of any other index), it will properly do an index seek on PK_Employee.

Comment: Well that's why I asked you to share the execution plan, what is tenantID and is it Indexed at all? You have a Where clause on a field and if this field doesnt have any index on it, it changes everything.

Comment: TenantId is the first field in every index in ApptDet. If you look at the screenshot in the link, it shows the proper 2301 records in index seek, but 29057 in an index scan to employee. Here's SentryOne plan: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uY4a0sx6eUZSh-lrhkl1PGOyshG62_U6

Answer (score 0):

> This query returns 500 order records, but has performed an Index Scan using IX_Employee_EmpName on the Employee table, which read 30,000 records.

SQL Server is a cost based optimizer, so it tries to choose a plan based on cost and in this  case it chose this index `IX_Employee_EmpName`. Since empid is the clustered key, it is by default added to all nonclustered indexes and SQL Server has the two columns it needs from this narrow index

Comment: Ok that would make sense if PK is automatically included in every index, but why does using this index cause an scan instead of a seek, causing a read of way more records than required?

Comment: since sqlserver is a cost based optimizer,see the cost for scan one and try using `PK_Employee` by force..

Comment: You can force index like this after the table `WITH (INDEX(pk_employee))`

Comment: Thank you. That perfectly answered my question. The IO and CPU cost is less when using the IX, even with the scan vs PK seek.